# SORT transformation takes forever

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I have a big XML file about 800 MB with many tags and attributes. I need to pull different values from this file, therefore, I have used many `SORT` and `JOIN` transformations. All of them work well and do not take too much time, except for the last `SORT` transformation shown in a red oval in the picture below. This takes forever.

[image]

If I use a smaller `XML` file, it will go thru and will not take too much time. So I assume the problem is with the size of dataset its dealing with. I was wondering if you know of any way that can help me handle this situation. Any property that needs to get changed to improve the performance of this particular case. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered writing a SQL query and using a Exec SQL step to update the state values instead of doing a lookup and merge? Also, are all of the sources XML? If so, you may want to pivot into a real table at some point. That will increase performance a lot.

Comment: @JacobH Please correct me if I'm not getting what you are suggesting, but I'm not "updating" and I don't have a "lookup". I'm just querying a small table of states to join state names based on state id. I can't see how I can use a Exec SQL task here.

Comment: Why do you have a step called "LKP" if you aren't looking up data? :) My question stands. You haven't given us any information other than you have a massive amount of merges and sorts from various data sources and one is slower than the others.

Comment: @JacobH that "LKP_State" is a table name :) What info you need to know? I'd like to give any related info if you ask more specifically.

Comment: You already gave the response unintentionally :) Tab has the same answer I'm trying to give you; that you need a table to make use of indexing in SQL if you want to speed up the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do much to speed up the Sort transformation in SSIS.  The best solution is to find a way to not have to use the Sort transformation at all.   This usually means putting the data into an indexed database table, and doing the sort in a SELECT...ORDER BY query.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, avoiding `SORT` doesn't seem to be an option for me as I need to use a MERGE JOIN to grab some state names from OLE DB source and Merge. I also don't have permission to create an ETL table for this and asking for that will be my last option.

Comment: If you are merging state names, and there are only about 50 or so possible names that you are merging in, you might get better performance from a lookup transformation instead of a merge join.  Especially if the state names don't change and can therefore be cached.   You don't have to sort the incoming rows before a lookup.

Comment: I thought about this also, but, the `MERGE JOIN` does a `left join`. `LOOK UP` only gives me Matching and Non-Matchings. I don't know of anyway that a `LOOK UP` can work as a left join.

Comment: If you send both matching and non-matching outputs of a lookup to a UNION ALL transformation, the end result would be a left join.

Comment: This is a good idea! I'll try it. I'm going to mark this as an answer, but it would be great (and will help others also) if you update your answer with this last comment. Thanks again!